# Setting Google street basemap language in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, basemap, internationalization

I use google street map as my project's basemap in QGIS: Using Tile Server: `https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}`.

As my computer default language is Chinese, when the basemap is loading, all the place names were present in Chinese, how can I change it to English?
I have already set the QGIS language to English (Option->General->Override system locale->English), but it does not work in google street basemap.

Comment: Are you in china?

Comment: yes, and MrXsquared's sloultion prefectly solved my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `&hl=en` to your URL.

So it looks like `https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&hl=en`.

Instead of `en` you can also use any other [language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes). Note that most names used on Google Maps are not available in all languages.

[Source](https://baumsicht.de/google-maps-ohne-plugin-in-qgis-verwenden/)